# Asserts not seeing element when using C#, Selenium web-driver, and NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am trying to write a test script for a website. I want to use the assert to verify the element is on the page before the next line of code runs, calling that element.

I am using a try/catch block with the assert. The assert can not see the element by Id or Xpath. It fails and the catch grabs it. 
Here is the fun part: The next line of code uses the same web element by Id or Xpath and it works. This has me stumped.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.higgins3.com/");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //Assert try catch block to see if search box is one the page.
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Id("s")).Displayed);
                Console.Write("Search box display . assert Pass");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not find Search Box . assert Fail");
            }
            // End Assert

            IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("s"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            element1.Click();
            element1.SendKeys("Printer");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the exception message so we can see what the error is. Not your exception message but the one thrown by Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This is element loading issue. You can use either implicitly wait or explicitly wait. Both waits throw exception after certain amount time. Try the following before checking of element displayed.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

This will be applicable for all find element/elements method.

My personal advice, don't use thread sleep until required as it is a static wait.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost never right to catch an AssertionException from NUnit. In this case, it appears that you might get either an AssertionException or a timeout from Selenium. By catching `Exception` you are claiming to know what to do for every possible exception that arises.

You should be able to do this without a try / catch by proper waiting. Then, after all the waits are complete, you can assert on the result.